# Function without a body

Tags: c++, c, windows

I was analyzing this code from the companion CD rom that comes with the book "Windows via C\C++" and I came across this statement

```
m_hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(dwFlags, dwProcessID);
```

where `dwFlags` and `dwProcessID` are DWORD's

And when I jumped to the defination of this function `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` I found this

```
HANDLE 
WINAPI
CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(
    DWORD dwFlags,
    DWORD th32ProcessID
    );
```

How could such a function without a body exist?

I tried to debug the code but the compiler doesn't step into this function, instead it simply steps over the first statement with a value of 0x00000754 stored in m_hSnapshot.

Comment: Damn. It was stupid of me to even ask such a question. I should have checked the msdn first. I don't even know why the author of the code placed the function prototype in the program when it is an API.

Comment: What a trip.  The first edition of this book is how I learned to write Windows programs.

Comment: Richter likely explains why he is providing his own prototype for this function.  Its possible that this was an undocumented or undeclared function at the time he wrote this (which was like 142 years ago).

Answer (score 7):

> How could such a function without a body exist?

It doesn't. What you're seeing is just a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype). The body is defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

What you see is not a function *definition* but a *declaration*. The actual definition is provided by dlls in Windows itself, linked to your executable.

Answer (score 0):

The function has a body, but it's just not visible.

That's just the declaration. If it was visible, Windows would be open source (don't laugh). C++ is a compiled language. Binary files are generated from code, the code itself isn't required to call a function.

Answer (score 0):

The body may be at different places, in a static or dynamic library that you link against for example.

Answer (score 0):

Its just a function to accept parameters, it is probably used by a method somewhere else, after user initialization. It looks like it is actually just getting a snapshot of the processID to display when you say go into the command prompt and request a process display.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's just a prototype for a function that's defined in an existing Windows DLL (Kernel32.dll)